# Change the background color of selected TextField

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating an app in which I have used user registration.In registration page, I have created many UITextFields.I wants that when a user select any TextField then its background Image is change. I uses the code to do that is:

```
- (IBAction)touchBegin:(id)sender
{
     //UILabel *opt = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    if (_text1.isSelected) {
         _text1.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_star_non_rating.png"];
    }
    else if (_text2.isSelected){
        _text2.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_star_non_rating.png"];
    }
    else if (_text3.isSelected){
        _text3.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_star_non_rating.png"];
    }
    else if (_text4.isSelected){
        _text4.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_star_non_rating.png"];
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

But I am not getting the result according to my need.
What should I use to get correct output?

Comment: what is your textfield style? Border style or what?

Answer (score 1):

be sure whether your textfield border style is UITextBorderStyleNone.

```
yourTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;

yourTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's better and easier to use UITextFieldDelegate methods like this, for example:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_star_non_rating"];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnImageForNormalStateOrSetNilBackground"];
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my code the if condition is not working properly. Which If/switch condition should I use to get the result(When select a TextField then its color is changed not others.  I want to know the correct if/switch condition to get the output.

Comment: In this methods you don not need to put an if/switch condition. The 'textfield' (UITextfield *) received in this method is the textfield that is editing.